# Upgrading to Quasar 2 breaks PreloadWebpackPlugin?

Tags: javascript, webpack, quasar

We recently upgraded to Quasar 2 and this resulted in `@vue/preload-webpack-plugin` throwing the following error:

```
(node:14265) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning:   TypeError: Cannot read property 'tap' of undefined
  
  - index.js:116 
    [myproject]/[@vue]/preload-webpack-plugin/src/index.js:116:65
  
  - Hook.js:154 SyncHook.lazyCompileHook
    [myproject]/[tapable]/lib/Hook.js:154:20
  
  - Compiler.js:631 Compiler.newCompilation
    [myproject]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:631:26
  
  - Compiler.js:667 
    [myproject]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:667:29
  
  - Hook.js:154 AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook
    [myproject]/[tapable]/lib/Hook.js:154:20
  
  - Compiler.js:662 Compiler.compile
    [myproject]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:662:28
  
  - Watching.js:77 
    [myproject]/[webpack]/lib/Watching.js:77:18
```

The relevant section of the `quasar.conf.js`:

```js
      extendWebpack (cfg) {
        cfg.plugins.push(new PreloadWebpackPlugin({
          rel: 'preload',
          as (entry) {
            if (/\.css$/.test(entry)) return 'style';
            if (/\.woff$/.test(entry)) return 'font';
            if (/\.png$/.test(entry)) return 'image';
            return 'script';
          }
        }));
        cfg.module.rules.push({
          enforce: 'pre',
          test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
          loader: 'eslint-loader',
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          options: {
            formatter: require('eslint').CLIEngine.getFormatter('stylish')
          }
        });
      }
```

Looking at the line in `preload-webpack-plugin` that is resulting in the error:

```js
    compiler.hooks.compilation.tap(
      this.constructor.name,
      compilation => {
        // this line below
        compilation.hooks.htmlWebpackPluginBeforeHtmlProcessing.tap(
          this.constructor.name,
          (htmlPluginData) => {
            if (skip(htmlPluginData)) {
              return
            }
            this.generateLinks(compilation, htmlPluginData)
          }
        )
```

Can anyone suggest how to resolve this issue?

Environment:

- NodeJS: 14.15.1
- @vue/preload-webpack-plugin: 1.1.2
- @quasar/app: 2.1.14